# How to query array contains in Haskell Esqueleto

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod, esqueleto

I'm trying to select all Events from the database that contain a Tag in the Event's tags column.

`Event` is a model with a column `tags` that is defined in Yesod's model file as `tags [Tag]`. Tag is a model that is simply `newtype Tag = Tag Text` with a lot of derivings including `PersistField` which should allow `Tag` types to be stored as `Text` types.

I would like to define a query that selects all events that contain a given tag in their tags column. Something like:

```
getEventsByTag :: Tag -> Handler Value
getEventsByTag tag = do
  events <- runDB findEvents :: Handler [Entity Event]
  return $ object ["events" ==. events]
 where
  findEvents =
    select $
      from $ \event -> do
        where_ $ (event ^. EventTags) `contains` (val tag)
        return event
```

The part I'm not sure how to do is the `contains` function. It doesn't seem likely that I can use any postgres array functions since Persistent stores arrays as varchars in postgres. In which case I could get fancy with `like`. I was actually able to get the result I wanted with this query in postgres: `select * from events where tags like '%"tag"%';` But I'm not sure how to translate this into Esqueleto's language. I tried using the `like` function but it requires both arguments to be instances of `SqlString` which I made `Tag` derive but had trouble figuring out how to make `[Tag]` derive without overlapping instances.